# A nested form loops through the has_many associated items. How do I display values like id in the f.fields_for ... loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

Hard to explain in the title.

I have this a nested form that has `category_items` and its associated (through has_many) `category_item_values`

```
<%= form_for([@category, @category_item], url: category_items_update_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.fields_for :category_item_values do |item_value| %>

         <%= item_value.label :value %> 
         <%= item_value.text_field :value %>

        <% end %>

      <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

There are 5 values associated to the item so it displays 5 inputs, one for each category_item_value associated to the given item.

Say in the category_item_values db there is a 'name' column and I want to display the value name above each category_item_value input. How do I do this?

What would I call to access the current categroy_item_value it is looping through and call .name on to display the name above its input

```
        <%= f.fields_for :category_item_values do |item_value| %>

          <%=  SOMETHING.name %>

         <%= item_value.label :value %> 
         <%= item_value.text_field :value %>

        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `item_value.object.name`